# how to change labeltext inside template in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, label, angular-components

I am having a angular component  here is my component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'labelnumeric',
    template: '<label>hello</label>'
})
```

here in template i am using hello as label text

and here component is defining in HTML control
here is my HTML

```
<labedate></labedate>
```

so on the basis of HTML control i want to change the label text how can i done this ?

is there is any possibility to set the name based on attributes ?

Comment: Angular (2,3,4,5) and AngularJS (1.x) are quite different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is @Input in your component

See the documentation here:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

What you basically need todo is to import Input and then define an input property in your component

```
@Component({
selector: 'labelnumeric',
template: '<label>{{something}}</label>'
})
export class XYZ {
@Input() something: string;
}
```

and then you can use this like so in the html part

```
<labelnumeric [something]= "Text"></labelnumeric>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is `@input`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'labelnumeric',
  template: `<label>{{numeric}}</label>`,
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() numeric: string;
}
```

Then use it like :

```
<labelnumeric numeric='10'></labelnumeric>
//OR
<labelnumeric [numeric]='your_varible'></labelnumeric>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackblitz-demo)** (Basic Working demo of `@input`)